# Create instance of class from other package?

Tags: java, package

I have 2 packages, `airline` and `userInterface`

In the `AirportMain` I am trying to create an instance of class `AirlineReservation` but it is from package `userInterface`, unlike my `AirportMain`.

I'm using:

```
AirlineReservation airlineReservation = new AirlineReservation();
```

but getting an error that it is not public in `AirlineReservation` so it cannot be accessed outside the package, but I do have:

```
public class AirlineReservation {
```

in class `AirlineReservation`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the constructor public too?

Comment: Did we do away with the homework tag?

Answer (score 1):

If the constructor for `AirlineReservation` is not declared `public`, that is your problem there. Make the constructor public.
If it is public, it's possible you need to put

```
import userInterface.AirlineReservation;
```

at the beginning of `AirportMain`.

Comment: @user3341642 make your constructor public

Comment: added the word public before my constructor and it worked... thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Make the constructor public and for more information about access modifier [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm).